# How to fix sudo apt-get update

Tags: ppa, configuration, software-sources

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, the terminal prints:

```
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flimm/ooo-thumbnailer/ubuntu 
       bionic Release 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu 
       bionic Release 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu 
       bionic Release 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

When I tried to remove those `ooo-thumbnailer`, `gwibber-daily`,
and `miro-releases`, the Terminal answered they didn't exist in the Directory. If so, how to make the Terminal not to mention something non-existent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your /etc/apt/sources.list is broken... I suggest that you find sources for your country and paste original lines in that file. In your case you can also comment out the lines which you think are causing the problem in sources.list.

Those lines you posted are from ppa repos and it seems like the server is offline from which you are pulling the packages.

Comment: Sorry, "find sources for your country" isn't clear. I got out of "my country."

Comment: Where are you from... for every country there is a ubuntu sources.list for each ubuntu distribution... for example I live in germany and I just google: "deutschland ubuntu sources.list" and I get this: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/sources.list/

Comment: Use DuckDuckGo then.

Comment: I see. Sometimes, it's easier to reinstall OS than search for solution to this or that problem.